# Not showing Achievements popups in different views

Tags: java, android, popup, google-play-games, achievements

I'm very stuck in here. 
I've implemented Google Play Games and I've created some achievements. When I sign in the popup is showing in my sign in activity but when I unlock an achievement in my finished game activity the popup don't appear.

In my sign in activity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // The signed in account is stored in the result.
            final GoogleSignInAccount signedInAccount = result.getSignInAccount();
            if (signedInAccount != null) {
                GamesClient gamesClient = Games.getGamesClient(Init.this,signedInAccount);
                gamesClient.setViewForPopups(findViewById(R.id.rel_init));

            }
```

but then I want to change and setviewForPopups to my finish activity because is where the user will unlock the achievement (end of the game).

The code there is:

```
   signedInAccount = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
    if(signedInAccount != null){
        GamesClient gamesClient = Games.getGamesClient(finish.this, signedInAccount);
        gamesClient.setViewForPopups(findViewById(R.id.popup_fin));
```

but when I unlock an achievement here nothing appears...

I've tried to set the popup_fin from the finish activity from the beginning in my sign in activity. Then the welcome popup appears in the finish activity but the unlocked achievement popups not.

Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: Same here, the welcome back popup appears with no problem, but when an achievement is unlocked nothing happens...